# Upload Photo to Document Library from iPad, Safari

Tags: 2013, mobile

We have:

- SharePoint 2013
- iPad
- Safari browser

We are trying to upload an Image from iPad's Photos to SharePoint Library. 
Problem: Upload document button is grayed out. No "Create button".

[image: FileUpload is blocked]

Can someone, please say if it's possible to make it work on iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the "Upload button" as you have highlighted in the screen shot above click the icon directly to the left of it entitled "New Document". If you click it on an iPad the "Add a document" panel will appear on the page. If you then click choose file you can either take a new photo or select a photo from your image library. Choose the picture you want and just hit okay and it will be uploaded.

-Just tested this with my own site on an iPad. Hope it works for you :D -

Here is a screen shot step by step:

This image is just the first step in your folder/where you are storing your images. In the top left you want to click on the "New Document" icon/dropdown.

After you click that dropdown this screen will display:
[image]

At this point you will want to click "Image". (Note - the form that pops up to choose your photo and add a description wouldn't show up for me unless there was at least one image already stored in the folder.)
This is an image of the pop up that appears (you will want to tap "Choose File")

[image]

After you select choose file a screen will display showing the various folders you have in your photo library on the iPad such as Moments or Camera Roll - choose the folder desired and then tap the photo you want to add and hit okay. (I had steps for this but I can't link more than 2 images - rep. is too low.)

Hopefully this helps - it was all done on SharePoint 2013 on an iPad via Safari.

Comment: Thanks for reply. No, I don't have a choice to create a document. I can only create a Folder. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Safari.

Comment: I just edited my answer to better explain the process I went through to add an image from the iPad.

Comment: Still, no options for files. I can only choose folders

Comment: Do you know for certain that your account has the correct permission level to add documents to this folder/library? That's the only other thing I can think of being the issue here. The option should be displayed otherwise. Maybe your group permission level just doesn't have the rights to upload documents or at least images?

Comment: Yes, of course. this is normal behavior for SharePoint on iPad. You won't have a way to upload a photo without some kind of a hack. I've already found a workaround. I will write about it later when I have time

Comment: Sorry, my process didn't work for you. Maybe there is a difference in the settings of your library compared to mine. For most cases however I believe that the process I described should work.